# PGHero - Docker - Monitor all databases in the cluster

Tags: postgresql, pghero

Is it possible to deploy a single standalone, docker instance, of PGHero and be able to use it to monitor all databases in the cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Use docker run to and a custom pghero.yml with the custom config.

The secret is map the pghero.yml (the -v), here is an example that I used:

```
databases:
   main:
     url: 'postgres://aaa:bbb@192.168.444.444:55432/pghero'
   dev:
     url: 'postgres://ccc:dddd@192.168.4456:5432/otherdb'
```

Run it:

```
docker run -tid --name pgdafhero -e PGHERO_USERNAME=xxx -e PGHERO_PASSWORD=yyy \
-p 8080:8080 \
-v $(pwd)/pghero.yml:/app/config/pghero.yml \
 ankane/pghero
```

check for a clean start

open the URL: HTTP://xxx:yyy@127.0.0.1:8080 to access the dashboard

Here, you can see the list of available databases (2) and the current selected one (1)

[image]

In summary, you can use a single docker to monitor all the databases that you need. Just add DB by DB in the yml file.